# Looping XML Values

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

I exported the .kml file for a place list created on google maps, this looks like so:

```
 <Placemark>
    <name>Name of first business here</name>
    <description><![CDATA[<div dir="ltr">Address etc
<br>Tel No
<br>www.example.com</div>]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#style17</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>1893891893891</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Second business</name>
    <description><![CDATA[<div dir="ltr">Address here 
<br>Tel no
<br>www.webaddress.com</div>]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#style5</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>7317783871871</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
<Placemark>
..
</Placemark>
..
```

I would simply like to loop through and echo the names out to the page.

I have tried loading the file as a simplexml file and using a foreach loop to attempt to read the values, with no success.

---

This code prints out just the first name, doesn't appear to loop, stops after first name:

```
<?php
    $distr = simplexml_load_file('../../media/Distributors.kml');
    foreach ($distr as $value) {
        echo '<li>' . $value->Placemark->name . '</li>';
    }
?>
```

This code looks like it should work, but prints nothing:

```
<?php
    $distr = simplexml_load_file('../../media/Distributors.kml');
    foreach ($distr->Placemark as $placemark) {
        echo '<li>' . $placemark->name . '</li>';
    }
?>
```

I've tried a few other combinations but neither seem to do what I want, what am I doing wrong?

Print_r dump:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Document] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => Distributors
            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [Style] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style17
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style5
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style4
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style18
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style15
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style20
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style6
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style23
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style22
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style11
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style7
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style12
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style3
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [22] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => style8
                                )

                            [IconStyle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Icon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [href] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [Placemark] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Rigibore Ltd
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [styleUrl] => #style17
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -5.399673,50.191875,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Rigibore Inc.
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [styleUrl] => #style5
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -88.320183,42.867550,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Vibha Technologies
                            [styleUrl] => #style4
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 77.568222,13.002831,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Centra-Tech bvba
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [styleUrl] => #style18
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 4.867222,51.141304,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => A B T Machine Tools & Tooling Ltd
                            [styleUrl] => #style15
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -4.324394,55.894394,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Cromwell Tools Ltd WDC
                            [styleUrl] => #style20
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -1.124264,52.585289,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Beijing Promise
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [styleUrl] => #style6
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 116.300972,39.945293,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Donini E Grandi Srl Do-Gra
                            [styleUrl] => #style23
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 11.331189,44.512886,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Euskron S.A.
                            [styleUrl] => #style22
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -1.947317,43.093163,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => H B Tools Ltd
                            [styleUrl] => #style11
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -2.865015,53.601593,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Monks & Crane Ltd
                            [styleUrl] => #style7
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -2.028771,52.547211,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Hudson Foster
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [styleUrl] => #style12
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -1.509982,53.665184,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => BIM Sp. z o.o.
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [styleUrl] => #style3
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 16.772060,52.437359,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Precise Tooling System
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [styleUrl] => #style9
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 103.875557,1.377493,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Campbell Peter Sales Ltd
                            [styleUrl] => #style2
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -3.949751,55.848644,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [15] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Obradors D R M, S.l.
                            [styleUrl] => #style16
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 2.171534,41.400570,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [16] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Multicarb CC T/A Multitrade Distributors
                            [styleUrl] => #style1
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 28.178808,-26.152639,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [17] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Howard Lee & Son
                            [styleUrl] => #style10
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -2.062812,52.471966,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [18] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Glendower Cutting Tools Ltd
                            [styleUrl] => #style21
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -1.105845,52.674934,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [19] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Finn A Værktøj A/S
                            [styleUrl] => #style13
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 9.853188,54.986698,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [20] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Flatley.PMG
                            [styleUrl] => #style14
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -6.337717,53.312447,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [21] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Iscar Tools Argentina Sa
                            [styleUrl] => #style19
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => -58.404968,-34.639957,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                    [22] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => Duroc Machine Tool AB
                            [styleUrl] => #style8
                            [Point] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [coordinates] => 18.092628,59.449158,0.000000
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Charlie, why don't you echo out the content of $distr? echo var_dump($distr); and at least we will know a thing or two about your results.

Comment: Used `print_r` with `<pre>`, better readability, added in main post, most of the styling stuff is irrelevant so I removed some of that due to char count.

Comment: Just for the record, I would like to tell you that there is a Document inside the main object and inside the Document there is a set of values, I believe you should search for your value inside the Document object of your main object.

Comment: Hmm I did try that before with no luck.  However, found a solution: `$distr = simplexml_load_file('../../media/Distributors.kml');
        for($i=0; $i < 23; $i++) {
         foreach ($distr as $value) {
             echo '<li>' . $value->Placemark[$i]->name . '</li>';
         }
     }`

Comment: However, the number 23 I would like to be dynamic, any `count` functions that I use on the array always return `1` or `0`...

Comment: @Charlie The `for` loop in your solution should just be an inner `foreach`, to look at the list of `Placemark` elements within each `$value`: `foreach ($distr as $value) { foreach ($value->Placemark as $placemark) { echo '<li>' . $placemark->name . '</li>'; } }`

Comment: The XML you have pasted is incomplete: it's not vaild as there is no outermost "root element", and it doesn't match what you show in the `print_r` output. This makes it tricky for us to reproduce your problem and solve it. You should always try to produce a concise example which is similar enough to your real code/data to reproduce the problem and test solutions.

Comment: Will keep that in mind for the future, I thought I'd posted everything that might have been relevant, as I didn't think the surrounding `<document>` tag mattered.  Your solution works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read xml file and loop through the xml elments .try something like this

```
<songs>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:40:26">
        <title>I left my heart on Europa</title>
        <artist>Ship of Nomads</artist>
    </song>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:27:42">
        <title>Oh Ganymede</title>
        <artist>Beefachanga</artist>
    </song>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:23:50">
        <title>Kallichore</title>
        <artist>Jewitt K. Sheppard</artist>
    </song>
</songs>
<?php

$dir = "home/";
$files = glob($dir."*.xml");
foreach($files as $file_xml)
{
$headernode = new SimpleXMLElement($file_xml,null,true);
foreach($headernode as $property)
{
echo $name = $property->first;
}

}

OR try something like this

 $mysongs = simplexml_load_file('songs.xml');
  echo $mysongs->song[0]->artist;


?>
```

Comment: Don't really need multiple xml files, glob function is irrelevant, also you were missing a semicolon in the foreach... anyway, that doesn't work, no results.

Comment: No luck, code used: `$distr = simplexml_load_file('../../media/Distributors.kml');
    echo $distr->Placemark[0]->name;`

Comment: Do your files renders ? send me file details where your xml file is and your php file .

Comment: Yes the file is loading absolutely fine, as said in the question I did manage to extract the name of a single business on the list, just it doesn't seem to loop using the same code.

Comment: The one I wrote.  I can't get any output from any of the solutions you posted.